# I get different view drawing in IOS SDK 5 from SDK 7

Tags: ios, ios7

In The attached screen shots the code is the same.

[image: Two versions of same product - same code - screen output is different by an offset]

The only differennce is - one was built with iOS SDK 5 (which shows OK) and the other with SDK 7 (which is presented on the screen with offset - BAD).

The screen output in IOS7 has unwanted vertical offset.  The blue rectangle area in SDK5 is painted over in IOS7.

How can I have the same screen output the same in IOS7 as it was before?

Comment: Have you checked you `Extend Edges` settings? (btw: are you using Storyboard or via code?)

Comment: no storyboard. all in code. a few xib files, but some vc-s are just plain code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to fix this with with the `Extend Edges` settings.
Your content vc should have something like this settings (in the IB):
[image]

The same can be done in code:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectBottom;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
```

Comment: The above for each View Controller?

Comment: Try it with your CollectionViewController (?). Play with this variables, to fit your demands.